# Is there a way to use multiple allMatch() in a stream instead of using the below form?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

```
return items.stream().allMatch(condition) && items.stream().allMatch(condition) && 
    items.stream().allMatch(condition);
```

Comment: If you share what conditions is, maybe we can suggest other solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can add all conditions in one `allMatch`:

```
return items.stream().allMatch(condition && condtion2 && condition3)
```

and it depends on your logic, maybe you can use better than this.